# How can I sample from a list without replacement when assigning variables to agents?

Tags: netlogo

I have a lists of values and I want the agents in my model to sample from these lists without replacement. The `n-of` primitive allows me to sample at random but, this means the values get duplicated sometimes, something that I want to avoid.

For example, if agent-1 gets a 1 from list 1, agent-2 should not be able to get this as well.

Hope you can help.

```
turtles-own [list1Vals list2Vals]
to test

  clear-all   
  crt 2 
  let list1 [1 2]
  let list2 [3 4]
  ask turtles [set xcor random-xcor 
    set ycor random-ycor
    set color red       
    set list1Vals n-of 1 list1
    set list2Vals n-of 1 list2 
     ] 

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to randomly choose an index value rather than randomly choosing from the list, because you can then use `item` to choose the list value and `remove-item` to remove it from the original list. More details in comments:

```
turtles-own [list1Vals list2Vals]

to test
  ca

  let list1 [1 2 3 4 5]

  crt 5 [
    ; Randomly choose an index based on the 
    ; length of list1
    let ind1 one-of range length list1

    ; Have the turtle choose from list1
    ; using that index
    set list1Vals item ind1 list1

    ; Remove the indexed value from list1
    set list1 remove-item ind1 list1

    show ( word "I chose " list1Vals ". list1 is now: " list1 )
  ] 
  reset-ticks
end
```

`test` outputs something like:

```
(turtle 1): "I chose 5. list1 is now: [1 2 3 4]"
(turtle 4): "I chose 4. list1 is now: [1 2 3]"
(turtle 0): "I chose 3. list1 is now: [1 2]"
(turtle 2): "I chose 2. list1 is now: [1]"
(turtle 3): "I chose 1. list1 is now: []"
```

Or

```
(turtle 1): "I chose 1. list1 is now: [2 3 4 5]"
(turtle 0): "I chose 4. list1 is now: [2 3 5]"
(turtle 4): "I chose 2. list1 is now: [3 5]"
(turtle 3): "I chose 5. list1 is now: [3]"
(turtle 2): "I chose 3. list1 is now: []"
```